# Data disappers from Cache - keys stay, but values are null

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, caching

We have several quite big ASP.NET 2.0 application written in C#, running on Windows Web Server 2008.
We use Cache quite often and until recently there were no problem.
However, for last few months we get random errors in methods using Cache. Although the key exists, the value Cache[key] seems to be null. Or there is a collection in Cache and all its elements are suddenly null (collection is initialized with constans, so these are not database issues).
How is that possible? Is there any known bug? Can that be server memory or disc failure?

Comment: It is the very idea of the Cache to drop Values when memory gets low (or after a certain amount of time). So Values become `null` : by design.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you populate your cache using `Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration` + `Cache.NoSlidingExpiration`, ASP.NET can remove items from the cache (e.g. when memory gets low).

Pass [`CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitempriority.aspx) to `Cache.Insert()` to prevent that from happening.

Comment: No, no, this is not the problem of normal Cache work. The problem is that we cache e.g. an ArrayList filled with some strings. Then after some time we take the ArrayList out from Cache and ArrayList[i] is null, although for sure we never put any null there.

Comment: @user34402: Then describe your problem a little better. Also post the relevant code.

Comment: In the question you say `Cache[key]` is null, now you say `(ArrayList<string>)Cache[key][i]` is null. It is not the same. Please post your cache store/retrieve code and clarify your question.